# Monitor Windows API withOUT drivers or injection - Can it be done?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7, 64-bit, hook

I have a list of a few Windows APIs I would like to monitor on both 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows.

Now, there are two basic approaches to this:

- Kernel based system wide hook driver - which won't work on Win 7 64 bit. And I'd like to refrain from using kernel drivers where possible in any OS.
- DLL Injection into specific processes. Again, I'd like to avoid this, if possible, so as to not be intrusive on many applications.

Now, the "if possible" part is the actual question here.
Is it at all possible to get the affect of the Kernel driver based hook (wherein when each of the hooked APIs is called, I get the required info passively) in a "friendlier" user mode?

My target in Win 7 (64 bit and 32 bit).
Other OSs are of lesser priority.

Comment: I think it might help if you provide list of APIs you want to monitor. I don't know other general ways but there might be some hooks for API calls you need.

Comment: If you want to monitor API calls without injecting code into the processes, or tampering with kernel mode, then all I can think of is run the OS and the apps to monitor in a VM that you control. I don't know if any VMs are available as a c library that you can install your monitoring code into.

Comment: No, the VM  option isn't viable.

Some of the APIs I'm looking to monitor are:
CreateProcess
TerminateProcess
AllocVM
Read VM
Write VM
CreateRemoteThread

FindWindow
GetDC
GetWindowDC
SendInput